# HTMl img to JPEG data for Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, binaryfiles

I am trying to send an HTML img element to the drive api . As I understand I need to send JPEG or in words the binary data . How do I extract this data out of the img element ?
Is this the same as creating a canvas element out of this img element and extracting its data Url as in canvas.toDataUrl() ? I tried this but it did not work . I managed to create a file in the drive but it leads to an improper JPEG call - this is not really the 'JPEG data' that needs to be sent. 
I did look around for this but must of the questions dealt with the FileReader API , where you 'readAsBinaryString' - but I have a different situation here.

Comment: use a lib to convert the dataURL to a blob and send your blob to google.

Comment: can't I do something like this in JS itself ; without an external lib ?

Comment: I tried doing this with https://github.com/ebidel/filer.js/blob/master/src/filer.js . This time drive api rejected the request that had blob - malformed multipart  request.

Comment: you can use FormData to make a blob upload look like an older file upload.

Comment: I am trying to follow this but it is not working . If I follow the example here https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#multipart , it mentions of JPEG data . What exactly is it ? How do I extract it from an img element ?